# Is Webhook URL necessary for OAuth Access Token?

Tags: slack-api

Is Webhook URL necessary for OAuth Access Token?
Prometheus Alertmanager has a place to write a Webhook URL, but is it necessary to write an OAuth Access Token?

What is OAuth Access Token used for?

Answer (score 0):

No. Webhook URLs and OAuth Access Tokens are very different concepts.

- Webhook URLs allow you to post a message to a Slack workspace and you only need to know the URL to do that.
- OAuth Access Tokens gives you access to use the [Slack Web API](https://api.slack.com/web), which has lot more functionality than just posting messages.

Check out [this page](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) on how OAuth works with Slack.

Comment: To Erik
Thank you for your polite answer.